# How to make bluetooth always discoverable

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I see in documentation that if you set the EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION extra's value to 0, the device is always discoverable.

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);    


discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);


startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

but I see this message in the mobile:

> an app want to enable bluetooth and make your device visible to other device for 120 seconds.

I see this problem in stackoverflow but always without any solution
any way to make the bluetooth always discoverable ?

NB: all values give 160 and not only 0 ,I try 100 for exemple

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION) does not promise that "0" is "always discoverable"

It says "120" seconds is deault, "300" seconds is maximum. And that's for good - I do not want any application makers making such decisions ("make bluetooth always discoverable") on my phone.

Comment: So there is no way to do that ? because I want to detect people using the same application by Bluetooth automatically and to detect it anytime there is a contact between 2 users having the same application they must having Bluetooth discoverable and not only enable. (I found the 0 option here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#java)

Comment: It was a security risk and it seems they eventually removed it

Comment: Ok thank u, so this will block my project, there is no other way to work with that , because I see some application using this function, If I use for example an old API level !

Comment: By the way I try other values like 100 and always still 160 not just 0